# Installing ffmpeg with homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to install ffmpeg and it's libraries with homebrew on a mac running osx (El Capitain). 
The installation completes however its seems only ffmpeg is installed and not ffprobe or drawtext.

I tried reinstalling with this command:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools
```

..but I get this

```
Warning:ffmpeg-3.0.2 already installed, it's just not linked
```

What am I missing? I have tried deleting and retrying the installation but the problem persists.

Comment: `brew link ffmpeg`?

Comment: Solved. That gave me

Comment: brew link --overwrite ffmpeg fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

To answer this question, you need to link up `ffmpeg`, but I'd run some housecleaning too.

First remove ffmpeg from your system:

```
$ brew uninstall ffmpeg
```

Now update all your brew packages and references.

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade
$ brew cleanup
```

Now install `ffmpeg` on your system, and link it up:

```
$ brew install ffmpeg --force
$ brew link ffmpeg
```

Now you should be good to go.

Comment: Works for me; note: on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, `ffmpeg` has no --force directive: `Warning: ffmpeg: this formula has no --force option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: Works with macOS Mojave version 10.14.2, thanks.

Comment: THANKS IT TOTALLY WORKED WITH MACOS X CATALINA BETA I LOVE YOU

Comment: `--all` is no longer an option.  Use `brew upgrade`